# Сортировка массива из 2х типов объектов

Tags: python, django

Добрый день, суть проблемы такова: имеются модели 2х типов - пусть будет А и В. Имеются выборки по ним, т.е.

```
a = A.objects.filter(parameters)
b = B.objects.filter(parameters)
```

Искомое: нужно получить один массив из этих 2х выборок(т.е. нужно их "склеить"), отсортированный по определённому полю(пусть будет поле 'date'). После конкатенации воедино получается неотсортированный массив. Сортировки по типу этих(из манов):

```
 sorted(result, key=operator.attrgetter('date'))
 sorted(result, key=lambda item: item.date)
```

ни к чему не приводят, данные по-прежнему остаются неотсортированными.
Знающие люди, подскажите, где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох, заработался я, такую глупую ошибку допустил... Не присваивал результат сортировки переменной, а просто так и оставлял, как указал в листинге. Оба способа рабочие, может кому-нибудь пригодятся, вот они, откорректированные:

```
from operator import attrgetter
sort_result = sorted(result, key=attrgetter('date'))
sort_result = sorted(result, key=lambda item: item.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на ответ, но все же очень заинтересовал ваш случай. Конкретно интересует будет ли работать конструкция следующего вида.

```
results = A.objects.filter(params) | B.objects.filter(params)
results = results.order_by('date')
```

Если будет работать, то вот вам и вариант.

Comment: Как ни жаль, но на первую же срочку: AssertionError at /search/
Cannot combine queries on two different base models.

Comment: Да, жалко. Видно жанго магия не настолько сильна ;)

Comment: Да достаточно и 2х способов, указанных мною выше :)